# How can I make a curl type http request using php?

Tags: php, drupal, curl

Basically I have a Drupal 6 site and a node type which I've named "rss". All of these nodes are available as an rss view at a specific url (ex: `http://mysite/rss/feed`).

When a node of that type gets created, all I need is to make an http request to a specific url (the details to that are irrelevant to this question).

So lets say I create a new "rss" post on my drupal site, after it gets submitted I need an http request to the url ex: `http://myapplication/blog?status=fetch`

I know that I can make such a request happen with the visit url function in actions core module, and "trigger" it on node creation (not of a specific type though) but I think it does exactly that, and actually VISITS the url, whereas I just need it to make a curl type request.

I'm also using the scheduler module, so posts of this type can be scheduled, so I would need to trigger the action in sync with the schedule, if it is scheduled to be posted at a certain time/date, that is.

I'm guessing I need to use some sort of hook functionality and make my own module, true? Or is there any other way of doing this because unfortunately I have limited php experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the curl extension in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php or find a library, or use something like Guzzle to make the requests to the HTTP endpoint. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/